# How to disable Google chrome url escape?

Tags: google-chrome, url

Hello is there a way to disable chrome adress bar url escape. For example if i type żąć.pl and when I copy it I receive xn--2dae36a.pl

I need Special characters because i want to run program with parameter that needs polish characters.

In mozilla i can easly disable escaping url.

Answer (score 0):

Try [copy-url](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-url/mkhnbhdofgaendegcgbmndipmijhbili) or similar extension.
Seems like Chrome always escape url and it's uninterruptible.